# Connecting to MS Access database using C++ using Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, database, visual-studio-2008, ms-access-2007

I need some serious help trying to connect to an Access database using VS 2008's C++. I have done this in C# but I cant figure this out in C++. I need to use C++ for the connection because I am grabbing data using pre-compiled C++ code. I would really appreciate some help with this. Thanks
I would like to odbc, but if you have another recommendation then I could change my mind.I am trying to connect to an Access database, the Northwind sample database, by following this example,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc811599.aspx

I am using a Windows 7 OS with Visual C++ 2008 for the compiler and IDE. The program is a console application. This example is specified for Access 2007 .accdb file types. Once I get it running correctly I will switch the path name, queries, and table names to my database. Below is the code that fails to build. I don't know what is causing this:

```
Includes-->
   fstream
cmath
complex
iostream
iomanip
vector
limits
stdlib.h
stdio.h
time.h
fcntl.h
string.h
ctype.h
icrsint.h

using namespace std;



#import C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\system\\ado\\msado15.dll rename("EOF",
      "AdoNSEOF")

_bstr_t bstrConnect="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data " 
                    "Source=C:\\Users\\lriley\\Documents\\Northwind 2007.mdb;";

HRESULT hr;

int main()
{
::CoInitialize(NULL);
const char* DAM = "ADO";

ADODB::_ConnectionPtr pConn("ADODB.Connection");
hr = pConn->Open(bstrConnect, "admin", "", ADODB::adConnectUnspecified);
if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    cout<<DAM<<": Successfully connected to database. Data source name:\n  "
        <<pConn->GetConnectionString()<<endl;

    // Prepare SQL query
    _bstr_t query = "SELECT Customers.[Company], Customers.[First Name] FROM "
                            "Customers;";
    cout <<DAM<<": SQL query \n  "<<query<<endl;

    // Execute
    ADODB::_RecordsetPtr pRS("ADODB.Recordset");
    hr = pRS->Open(query,
        _variant_t((IDispatch *) pConn, true),
        ADODB::adOpenUnspecified,
        ADODB::adLockUnspecified,
        ADODB::adCmdText);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        cout<<DAM<<": Retrieve schema info for the given result set: "<< endl;
        ADODB::Fields* pFields = NULL;
        hr = pRS->get_Fields(&pFields);
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr) && pFields && pFields->GetCount() > 0)
        {
            for(long nIndex=0; nIndex < pFields->GetCount(); nIndex++)
            {
                cout << " | "<<_bstr_t(pFields->GetItem(nIndex)->GetName());
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << DAM << ": Error: Number of fields in the " <<
                           "result is set to zero." << endl;
        }
        cout<<DAM<<": Fetch the actual data: " << endl;
        int rowCount = 0;
        while (!pRS->AdoNSEOF)
        {
            for(long nIndex=0; nIndex < pFields->GetCount(); nIndex++)
            {
                cout<<" | "<<_bstr_t(pFields->GetItem(nIndex)->GetValue());
            }
            cout<< endl;
            pRS->MoveNext();
            rowCount++;
        }
        cout<<DAM<<": Total Row Count:  " << rowCount << endl;
    }
    pRS->Close();
    pConn->Close();
    cout<<DAM<<": Cleanup Done" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout<<DAM<<" : Unable to connect to data source: "<<bstrConnect<<endl;
}
::CoUninitialize();
return 0;
}
```

I recieve the following error when I try to build it:

```
fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add #include "stdafx.h" to your source?   

c:\users\lriley\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\test12\test12\test12.cpp
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Dante

Comment: Here's a good starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd4ck1tt(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Repeating the error message: "Did you forget to add `#include "stdafx.h"` to your source?". If you're using precompiled headers `#include "stdafx.h"` must be the very first non-comment line of every compilation unit.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's been a while, but you are going to need something like: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714562%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, look at SQLConnect...,  a lot of variations to a theme, but the 2nd parameter is basically the path to your access db (*.mdb) file.

good luck.

Answer (score -1):

You just have to give in file properties *. Cpp

-> Precompiled Header-No Precompiled Headers

Use precompiled header file - Stdafx.h xxxx

Comment: Questions and answers on SO should be in English. Understood that it may not be your native language, but try to the best of your ability to write using English.

Comment: I tried a rough translation, but please edit this if it misses your original meaning.