# How to work with .mdb databases using Visual C++ (Not C++/CLI)?

Tags: c++, ms-access, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, ado

I'm becoming insane currently because I am not able to find a solution to the following task:

I want to

- read out data from tables inside a MS Access .mdb database
- manipulate said data and
- write it back into the same database
- do all that with Visual C++ (not with CLI as I would have to adjust lots of already existing code)

To do so, I tried to use the solution provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/cc811599(v=office.12)#ado), which uses ADO to work with the Northwind 2007.accdb database (It shouldn't be a problem that they access .accdb instead of .mdb right?). I copypasted the code given there into an empty project in VS2017 x64, only adjusted the sourcepath of the Northwind database and changed the following line

```
hr = pConn->Open(bstrConnect, "admin", "", ADODB::adConnectUnspecified);
```

to

```
HRESULT hr = pConn->Open(bstrConnect, "admin", "", ADODB::adConnectUnspecified);
```

because otherwise hr isn't defined. (Was this an incorrect adjustment?)

I have MS Access 2016 64bit version installed.

Now here is my code:

```
#import <C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\System\\ado\\msado15.dll> rename( "EOF", "AdoNSEOF" )
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    _bstr_t bstrConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Public\\Downloads\\Northwind 2007.accdb;";

    // Shows the Data Access Method used in this sample.
    const char* DAM = "ADO";

    ADODB::_ConnectionPtr pConn("ADODB.Connection");
    HRESULT hr = pConn->Open(bstrConnect, "admin", "", ADODB::adConnectUnspecified);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        cout << DAM << ": Successfully connected to database. Data source name:\n  "
            << pConn->GetConnectionString() << endl;

        // Prepare SQL query.
        _bstr_t query = "SELECT Customers.[Company], Customers.[First Name] FROM Customers;";
        cout << DAM << ": SQL query:\n  " << query << endl;

        // Excecute the query and create a record set.
        ADODB::_RecordsetPtr pRS("ADODB.Recordset");
        hr = pRS->Open(query,
            _variant_t((IDispatch *)pConn, true),
            ADODB::adOpenUnspecified,
            ADODB::adLockUnspecified,
            ADODB::adCmdText);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
            cout << DAM << ": Retrieve schema info for the given result set: " << endl;
            ADODB::Fields* pFields = NULL;
            hr = pRS->get_Fields(&pFields);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pFields && pFields->GetCount() > 0) {
                for (long nIndex = 0; nIndex < pFields->GetCount(); nIndex++) {
                    cout << " | " << _bstr_t(pFields->GetItem(nIndex)->GetName());
                }
                cout << endl;
            } else {
                cout << DAM << ": Error: Number of fields in the result set is 0." << endl;
            }

            cout << DAM << ": Fetch the actual data: " << endl;
            int rowCount = 0;
            while (!pRS->AdoNSEOF) {
                for (long nIndex = 0; nIndex < pFields->GetCount(); nIndex++) {
                    cout << " | " << _bstr_t(pFields->GetItem(nIndex)->GetValue());
                }
                cout << endl;
                pRS->MoveNext();
                rowCount++;
            }
            cout << DAM << ": Total Row Count: " << rowCount << endl;
        }

        pRS->Close();
        pConn->Close();
        cout << DAM << ": Cleanup. Done." << endl;
    } else {
        cout << DAM << ": Unable to connect to data source: " << bstrConnect << endl;
    }



    return 1;
}
```

The code compiles but in msado15.tlh which is generated by the import directive there are 52 errors E0102 shown (for different lines but always the same error), the description being: The Forward declaration of the enumeration type doesn't comply to the standard (*rough translation, I think it gets the point across*). (As a side question: When using the import directive, where in the project properties do I have to link the msado15.dll path? I added the *C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado* path to the Include directory, was that right?)

Furthermore running the .exe or executing it in Powershell doesn't work, Windows gives out the message "*MYPROGRAM.exe isn't running anymore*" with the only option to close the program.

**What am I doing wrong? Have I chosen the wrong approach to what in my eyes seems to be a task that should be quite easy to solve (shouldn't be that hard to read out a damn table in Visual C++)?**

Is there maybe a better way to work with .mdb databases (like using DAO, ODBC or OLE DB for example) and are there working up-to-date code samples that one could work with or a nice documentation/tutorial that explains step-by-step how to connect to the database and shows how to read from and write into it?

EDIT1: A_Singh7 provided the following solutions:

1. define ghr as a global variable
2. change the return value of the main function to 0
3. Use the code provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445243/connecting-to-ms-access-database-using-c-using-visual-studio-2008)

The first two solutions didn't do the trick so I tried it with the code from solution 3. This is the output in Powershell i receive:

```
ADO: Successfully connected to database. Data source name:
  Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=admin;Data Source=C:\Users\Public\Downloads\Northwind 2007.accdb;Mode=Share Deny None;Jet OLEDB:System database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=1;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation=False;
ADO: SQL query
  SELECT Customers.[Company], Customers.[First Name] FROM Customers;
```

Afterwards, the .exe sadly crashes and I still have to figure out why. Nonetheless establishing a connection to the database seems to work, which was the main issue I had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to declare hr as a global variable.
That’s like,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

HRESULT hr;
 int main ()
 {
       // your code 
       // the line hr = pConn->Open(bstrConnect, "admin", "", ADODB::adConnectUnspecified); should remain as it is 
 }
```

First try the above, if it doesn’t work, try changing return 1; to return 0;.
If that even doesn’t work, see here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc811599.aspx
Take help from here after that :
[Connecting to MS Access database using C++ using Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445243/connecting-to-ms-access-database-using-c-using-visual-studio-2008)
Here you just need to include the file stafdx.h as a header to make the code work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Sadly both solutions didn't work. There are still the forward declaration errors in msado15.tlh as well as the fact that running the .exe doesn't work.

Comment: Take a look at the answer again.

Comment: When it comes to access databases and drivers the bitness if your app is important. If your driver is 64 bit then your app must be 64 bit. I use CDatabase and JET.

Comment: On my pc mdb uses 32 bit driver. But accdb uses 64 bit driver.

Comment: Is that what you want, Is the code doing your work ?

Comment: You can accordingly work on your program then, because the compile time errors are gone.

Comment: Please accept it as an answer if you really find it helpfull. Thanks!

Comment: The connection to the database finally works now, or else it wouldn't display the according message in Powershell (see my edit in the question). I need to examine why the code fails to select data from the table and crashes. Additionally I still get the forward declaration errors. Nonetheless thank you very much for answering the main point of my question (How to connect to a database)! Help from anyone regarding both the forward-declaration-errors as well as why the code crashes is greatly appreciated. @AndrewTuckle: How do I find out if my .mdb uses 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Not mention. It is the duty of our to help you.